# Escaping apostrophes/ticks in translator.to_cypher_queries method with GQLAlchemy

Tags: memgraphdb

I have an issue in my code Python code. I'm using GQLAlchemy and Memgraph 2.7

The function cypherQueryCreator.createCypherQuery in my program doesn't appear to be handling apostrophes (ticks) correctly. I have a node in a NetworkX graph that looks kind fo like this:

```
netNode = (15981, { 'category': 'Lexeme', 'Term': "Can't", 'Phonetics': 'k æ n t' })
```

When I watn to generate a cypher query, the output that I get is `CREATE (:Lexeme {Term: 'Can't', Phonetics: 'k æ n t', id: 15981});` and it is not a wonder that it doesn't work since `\` is missing in front of `'`. I was hoping to get this code `CREATE (:Lexeme {Term: 'Can\'t', Phonetics: 'k æ n t', id: 15981});`

Do you have any tips for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, and there is a workaround solution offert in [GitHub issue](https://github.com/memgraph/gqlalchemy/issues/249). The code that should help you is `escape_apostrophes = lambda x: re.compile(r"(['])").sub(r"\\'", x)`